# How docker images are identified with sha?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

There is an official `busybox:1.36.1` docker image on Dockerhub ([link](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/busybox/1.36.1/images/sha256-67a8ef886e2ca4055f00e7cd13aedb9b24148c1451a6832d16fcc997a157eedc?context=explore)).

It has 3 different sha:

1. when I pull it, I see `Digest: sha256:2376a0c12759aa1214ba83e771ff252c7b1663216b192fbe5e0fb364e952f85c`
2. when I `docker images` it, I see `IMAGE ID 5242710cbd55`
3. on [dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/busybox/1.36.1/images/sha256-67a8ef886e2ca4055f00e7cd13aedb9b24148c1451a6832d16fcc997a157eedc?context=explore) I see `Digest:sha256:67a8ef886e2ca4055f00e7cd13aedb9b24148c1451a6832d16fcc997a157eedc`

```
$ docker pull busybox:1.36.1
1.36.1: Pulling from library/busybox
Digest: sha256:2376a0c12759aa1214ba83e771ff252c7b1663216b192fbe5e0fb364e952f85c
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:1.36.1
docker.io/library/busybox:1.36.1

$ docker images busybox
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
busybox      1.36.1    5242710cbd55   2 weeks ago   4.26MB
```

Why are these 3 sha differ? Which one identifies docker image? Image ID is not image sha?